# Creating a Python Timer without running the function

Tags: python, timer

Is it possible in Python to create/setup a timer with threading, but not run the function until thread.start() is called? I've setup a perpetual timer like so:

```
class perpetualTimer():
  enabled = False
  Interval = 0
  def __init__(self,t,hFunction):
      print("init")
      self.t=t
      self.Interval = t
      self.hFunction = hFunction
      self.thread = Timer(self.t,self.handle_function)

  def handle_function(self):
      print("handle")
      print(self.hFunction.__name__)
      self.hFunction()
      self.thread = Timer(self.t,self.handle_function)
      self.thread.start()

  def start(self):
      print("start")
      self.thread = Timer(self.Interval,self.handle_function)
      self.thread.start()

  def stop(self):
      print("stop")
      self.thread.cancel()
def foo():
  print("foo")
```

And then create it:

```
tmr = perpetualTimer(5,foo())
```

By then running the program, I get a print out of "foo", followed by "init"... Not what I want.... I just want it to print "init"

Answer (score 0):

When writing

```
tmr = perpetualTimer(5,foo())
```

You say "call perpetualTimer on 5 and the result of a call to foo". That is why "foo" is printed before "init".

Looking at your code it seems to me like you are rather looking for

```
tmr = perpetualTimer(5,foo)
```

passing only a reference to the function!

Comment: Yes, I realised that shortly after posting the question. Rookie error...

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: the call to perpetualTimer(5,foo()) should actually be

```
 tmr = perpetualTimer(5,foo)
```